# Updating and Resolving Comments in Google Sheet

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I would like to update/resolve comments on google spreadsheets using a service account. Currently following the [GDrive V3 API guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/comments/update#python);
The API explorer on the page works well but I am unable to replicate it on Python.

GET and LIST methods work fine but PATCH keeps returning the old content and wouldn't update.

Heres my code:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials_file = './.config/gspread/service_account.json'
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata']
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(credentials_file, scopes=scope)
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials = credentials)
service.comments().update(commentId=<<commentId>>, fileId=<<fileId>>, fields='content', body={'content': 'new comment', 'resolved': True}).execute()

>>> returns {'content': 'old comment'}
```

Any idea what's wrong? Appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi ! I was able to run this correctly with my account. Does it work when you don't use a service account? Also, did you grant [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) to your service account?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion! It works when I use the OAuth 2.0 Client credentials (:

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Mateo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12835757/mateo-randwolf), patching of comments works when using the OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials (Secret key file)